# Global variables and the .data section

Tags: c, assembly, static, global-variables, sections

Is a variable that is stored in the `.data` section by definition a global variable that has program scope? In other words are these two words synonymous and one implies the other, or, for example would it be possible to have a `global` variable that is not stored in the `.data` section, or a label/variable that is not global?

Just to give a basic example:

```
// this is compiled as in the .data section with a .globl directive
char global_int = 11;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

}
```

Would compile to something like:

```
global_int:
        .byte   11
main:
    ...
```

But I'm seeing if the two terms -- global and "in the .data section" are the same thing or if there are counterexamples.

Comment: Given `const char x = 0;`, I believe that the compiler could put `x` into a `.rodata` section, or even the `.bss` section.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks, yes I tried it in compiler explorer and it goes into `.rodata`. Why the `.bss` though?

Comment: `.bss` is zeroed at load time. So any variable that's initialized to zero could potentially be placed into the `.bss` section.

Comment: Hint: see what happens with `static char nonglobal_int = 11;`, defined either inside or outside `main`.

Comment: The `.data` section is for mutable data in static storage class.  Not every such datum is global (e.g. local `static` variables aren't).  Not every global datum is in there (e.g. variables of thread-local storage class aren't).

Comment: @NateEldredge that's interesting -- it seems if it's `static` it includes it but without the `globl` directive -- is that correct?

Comment: At the end of the day, section names are just a matter of convention. The C standard says nothing about sections. As long as the compiler, linker and loader all agree, any names can be used for the sections. In embedded code, it's not unusual for the programmer to create custom sections to better control where variables are stored, e.g. internal vs. external ROM, and internal vs. external RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different concepts: Which "section" a variable goes into and its "visibility"

---

For comparison, I've add a `.bss` section variable:

```
char global_int = 11;
char nondata_int;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
}
```

Compiling  with `cc -S` produces:

```
    .file   "fix1.c"
    .text
    .globl  global_int
    .data
    .type   global_int, @object
    .size   global_int, 1
global_int:
    .byte   11
    .comm   nondata_int,1,1
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Note the `.data` to put the `global_int` variable in the data section. And, `.comm` to put `nondata_int` into the `.bss` section

Also, note the `.globl` to make the variables have global visibility (i.e. can be seen by other `.o` files).

Loosely, `.data` and/or `.bss` are the *sections* that the variables are put into. And, global [`.globl`] are the visibility. If you did:

```
static int foobar = 63;
```

Then, `foobar` would go into the `.data` section but be local. In the `nm` output below, instead of `D`, it would be `d` to indicate local/static visibility. Other `.o` files would *not* be able to see this [or link to it].

---

An `nm` of the `.o` program produces:

```
0000000000000000 D global_int
0000000000000000 T main
0000000000000001 C nondata_int
```

---

And, an `nm -g` of the final executable produces:

```
000000000040401d B __bss_start
0000000000404018 D __data_start
0000000000404018 W data_start
0000000000401050 T _dl_relocate_static_pie
0000000000402008 R __dso_handle
000000000040401d D _edata
0000000000404020 B _end
0000000000401198 T _fini
000000000040401c D global_int
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000401000 T _init
0000000000402000 R _IO_stdin_used
0000000000401190 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000401120 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000401106 T main
000000000040401e B nondata_int
0000000000401020 T _start
0000000000404020 D __TMC_END__
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> thanks for this answer. Regarding And, `.comm` to put `nondata_int` into the `.bss` section. Could you please explain that a bit? I don't see any reference to .bss so how are those two related?

Sure. There's probably a more rigorous explanation, but loosely, when you do:

```
int nondata_int;
```

You are defining a "common" section variable [the historical origin is from Fortran's common].

When linking [to create the final executable], if *no* other `.o` [or `.a`] has declared a value for it, it will be put into the `.bss` section as a `B` symbol.

But, if *another* `.o` *has* defined it (e.g. `define_it.c`):

```
int nondata_int = 43;
```

There, `define_it.o` will put it in the `.data` section as a `D` symbol

Then, when you link the two:

```
gcc -o executable fix1.o define_it.o
```

Then, in `executable`, it will go to the `.data` section as a `D` symbol.

So, `.o` files have/use `.comm` [the assembler directive] and `C` common section.

Executables have only `.data`, and `.bss`. So, given the `.o` files a common symbol goes to [is promoted to] `.bss` if it has *never* been initialized and `.data` if *any* `.o` has initialized it.

Loosely, `.comm`/C is a suggestion and `.data` and `.bss` is a "commitment"

This is a nicety of sorts. Technically, in `fix1.c`, if we *knew* beforehand that we were going to be linked with `define_it.o`, we would [probably] want to do:

```
extern char nondata_int;
```

Then, in `fix1.o`, the would be marked as an "undefined" symbol (i.e. `nm` would show `U`).

But, then, if `fix1.o` were *not* linked to anything that defined the symbol, the linker would complain about an undefined symbol.

The common symbol allows us to have *multiple* `.o` files that *each* do:

```
int nondata_int;
```

They all produce `C` symbols. The linker combines all to produce a *single* symbol.

So, again common `C` symbols are:

I want a global named X and I want it to be the same X as found in any other `.o` files, but don't complain about the symbol being multiply defined. If *one* [and *only* one] of those `.o` files gives it an *initialized* value, I'd like to benefit from that value.

Historically ...

IIRC [and I could be wrong about this], common was added [to the linker] to support Fortran `COMMON` declarations/variables.

That is, all fortran `.o` files just declared a symbol as common [its concept of global], but the fortran linker was expected to combine them.

Classic/old fortran could only specify a variable as `COMMON` (i.e. in C, equivalent to `int val;`) but fortran did *not* have global initializers (i.e. it did *not* have `extern int val;` or `int val = 1;`)

This common was useful for C, so, at some point it was added.

In the good old days (tm), the common linker type did *not* exist and one had to have an explicit `extern` in all but one `.o` file and one [and only one] that declared it. That `.o` that declared it could define it with a value (e.g.) `int val = 1;` or *without* (e.g.) `int val;` but all other `.o` files had to use `extern int val;`

Comment: thanks for this answer. Regarding `And, .comm to put nondata_int into the .bss section`. Could you please explain that a bit? For example from here https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Comm.html#Comm I don't see any reference to .bss so how are those two related?

Comment: thanks for the update! Also regarding, `Executables have only .data, and .bss.` -- what about the `rodata` section? Or are you including that in the `data` section?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I guess what I said could be better phrased as "don't have `.comm` sections". When you have special linking requirements, you can add (e.g): `__attribute__((section(".init3"))` and have the linker bunch them together as you'd like.