# "Multiple definition of" "first defined here" on GCC 10.2.1 but not GCC 8.3.0

Tags: c, linux, gcc, standards, header-files

I've had a bit of a look around Stackoverflow and the wider Internet and identified that the most common causes for this error are conflation of *declaration* (`int var = 1;`) and *definition* (`int var;`), and including `.c` files from `.h` files.

My small project I just split from one file into several is not doing any of these things. I'm *very* confused.

I made a copy of the project and deleted all the code in the copy (which was fun) until I reached here:

##### main.c

```c
#include "a.h"

int main() {
    
}
```

##### a.h

```c
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

int test;

#endif
```

##### a.c

```c
#include "a.h"
```

Pretty much as canonical as it gets, right? And yet...

```
$ rm *.o; gcc -g -c a.c; gcc -g -c main.c; gcc -o main main.o a.o
/usr/bin/ld: a.o:/.../a.h:5: multiple definition of `test'; main.o:/.../a.h:5: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

WAT :(

It was around this time I started questioning my configuration and tried another machine, accessing the exact same files over NFS.

```
$ rm *.o; gcc -g -c a.c; gcc -g -c main.c; gcc -o main main.o a.o
$ ./main
$ echo $?
0
```

Oooh no. What did I break on the first machine...

Hopefully my issue is rather that Something Quietly Changed between **GCC 8.3.0 (working)** and **GCC 10.2.1 (failing)**? Perhaps the newer version of GCC is defaulting to a newer C standard or something, which specifies different behavior in this area?

Alternatively perhaps it's configuration-related (this is all stock Debian). Here's the output of `gcc -dumpspecs` for both versions:

8.3.0:

```js
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc -dumpspecs
*asm:
%{m16|m32:--32}  %{m16|m32|mx32:;:--64}  %{mx32:--x32}  %{msse2avx:%{!mavx:-msse2avx}}

*asm_debug:
%{%:debug-level-gt(0):%{gstabs*:--gstabs}%{!gstabs*:%{g*:--gdwarf2}}} %{fdebug-prefix-map=*:--debug-prefix-map %*}

*asm_final:
%{gsplit-dwarf: 
   objcopy --extract-dwo     %{c:%{o*:%*}%{!o*:%b%O}}%{!c:%U%O}      %{c:%{o*:%:replace-extension(%{o*:%*} .dwo)}%{!o*:%b.dwo}}%{!c:%b.dwo} 
   objcopy --strip-dwo       %{c:%{o*:%*}%{!o*:%b%O}}%{!c:%U%O}     }

*asm_options:
%{-target-help:%:print-asm-header()} %{v} %{w:-W} %{I*}  %{gz|gz=zlib:--compress-debug-sections=zlib} %{gz=none:--compress-debug-sections=none} %{gz=zlib-gnu:--compress-debug-sections=zlib-gnu} %a %Y %{c:%W{o*}%{!o*:-o %w%b%O}}%{!c:-o %d%w%u%O}

*invoke_as:
%{!fwpa*:   %{fcompare-debug=*|fdump-final-insns=*:%:compare-debug-dump-opt()}   %{!S:-o %|.s |
 as %(asm_options) %m.s %A }  }

*cpp:
%{posix:-D_POSIX_SOURCE} %{pthread:-D_REENTRANT}

*cpp_options:
%(cpp_unique_options) %1 %{m*} %{std*&ansi&trigraphs} %{W*&pedantic*} %{w} %{f*} %{g*:%{%:debug-level-gt(0):%{g*} %{!fno-working-directory:-fworking-directory}}} %{O*} %{undef} %{save-temps*:-fpch-preprocess}

*cpp_debug_options:
%{d*}

*cpp_unique_options:
%{!Q:-quiet} %{nostdinc*} %{C} %{CC} %{v} %{I*&F*} %{P} %I %{MD:-MD %{!o:%b.d}%{o*:%.d%*}} %{MMD:-MMD %{!o:%b.d}%{o*:%.d%*}} %{M} %{MM} %{MF*} %{MG} %{MP} %{MQ*} %{MT*} %{!E:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!MT:%{!MQ:%{MD|MMD:%{o*:-MQ %*}}}}}}} %{remap} %{g3|ggdb3|gstabs3|gxcoff3|gvms3:-dD} %{!iplugindir*:%{fplugin*:%:find-plugindir()}} %{H} %C %{D*&U*&A*} %{i*} %Z %i %{E|M|MM:%W{o*}}

*trad_capable_cpp:
cc1 -E %{traditional|traditional-cpp:-traditional-cpp}

*cc1:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-cc:%(cc1_cpu) %{profile:-p};:%(cc1_cpu) %{profile:-p} %{!mglibc:%{!muclibc:%{!mbionic: -mbionic}}} %{!fno-pic:%{!fno-PIC:%{!fpic:%{!fPIC: -fPIC}}}}}

*cc1_options:
%{pg:%{fomit-frame-pointer:%e-pg and -fomit-frame-pointer are incompatible}} %{!iplugindir*:%{fplugin*:%:find-plugindir()}} %1 %{!Q:-quiet} %{!dumpbase:-dumpbase %B} %{d*} %{m*} %{aux-info*} %{fcompare-debug-second:%:compare-debug-auxbase-opt(%b)}  %{!fcompare-debug-second:%{c|S:%{o*:-auxbase-strip %*}%{!o*:-auxbase %b}}}%{!c:%{!S:-auxbase %b}}  %{g*} %{O*} %{W*&pedantic*} %{w} %{std*&ansi&trigraphs} %{v:-version} %{pg:-p} %{p} %{f*} %{undef} %{Qn:-fno-ident} %{Qy:} %{-help:--help} %{-target-help:--target-help} %{-version:--version} %{-help=*:--help=%*} %{!fsyntax-only:%{S:%W{o*}%{!o*:-o %b.s}}} %{fsyntax-only:-o %j} %{-param*} %{coverage:-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage} %{fprofile-arcs|fprofile-generate*|coverage:   %{!fprofile-update=single:     %{pthread:-fprofile-update=prefer-atomic}}}

*cc1plus:


*link_gcc_c_sequence:
%{static|static-pie:--start-group} %G %L    %{static|static-pie:--end-group}%{!static:%{!static-pie:%G}}

*link_ssp:
%{fstack-protector|fstack-protector-all|fstack-protector-strong|fstack-protector-explicit:}

*endfile:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{Ofast|ffast-math|funsafe-math-optimizations:crtfastmath.o%s}    %{mpc32:crtprec32.o%s}    %{mpc64:crtprec64.o%s}    %{mpc80:crtprec80.o%s} %{fvtable-verify=none:%s;      fvtable-verify=preinit:vtv_end_preinit.o%s;      fvtable-verify=std:vtv_end.o%s}    %{static:crtend.o%s;      shared|static-pie|!no-pie:crtendS.o%s;      :crtend.o%s}    crtn.o%s    %{fopenacc|fopenmp:crtoffloadend%O%s};:%{Ofast|ffast-math|funsafe-math-optimizations:crtfastmath.o%s}    %{mpc32:crtprec32.o%s}    %{mpc64:crtprec64.o%s}    %{mpc80:crtprec80.o%s} %{shared: crtend_so%O%s;: crtend_android%O%s}}

*link:
%{!r:--build-id} %{!static|static-pie:--eh-frame-hdr} %{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{m16|m32|mx32:;:-m elf_x86_64}                    %{m16|m32:-m elf_i386}                    %{mx32:-m elf32_x86_64}   --hash-style=gnu   %{shared:-shared}   %{!shared:     %{!static:       %{!static-pie:     %{rdynamic:-export-dynamic}     %{m16|m32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-i386.so.1;:/lib/ld-linux.so.2}}}}   %{m16|m32|mx32:;:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld64-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker64;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1;:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2}}}}       %{mx32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ldx32-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linkerx32;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-x32.so.1;:/libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2}}}}}}     %{static:-static} %{static-pie:-static -pie --no-dynamic-linker -z text}};:%{m16|m32|mx32:;:-m elf_x86_64}                    %{m16|m32:-m elf_i386}                    %{mx32:-m elf32_x86_64}   --hash-style=gnu   %{shared:-shared}   %{!shared:     %{!static:       %{!static-pie:        %{rdynamic:-export-dynamic}     %{m16|m32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-i386.so.1;:/lib/ld-linux.so.2}}}}   %{m16|m32|mx32:;:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld64-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker64;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1;:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2}}}}       %{mx32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ldx32-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linkerx32;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-x32.so.1;:/libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2}}}}}}     %{static:-static} %{static-pie:-static -pie --no-dynamic-linker -z text}} %{shared: -Bsymbolic}}

*lib:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{pthread:-lpthread} %{shared:-lc}    %{!shared:%{profile:-lc_p}%{!profile:-lc}};:%{shared:-lc}    %{!shared:%{profile:-lc_p}%{!profile:-lc}} %{!static: -ldl}}

*link_gomp:


*libgcc:
%{static|static-libgcc|static-pie:-lgcc -lgcc_eh}%{!static:%{!static-libgcc:%{!static-pie:%{!shared-libgcc:-lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state}%{shared-libgcc:-lgcc_s%{!shared: -lgcc}}}}}

*startfile:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{shared:;      pg|p|profile:%{static-pie:grcrt1.o%s;:gcrt1.o%s};      static:crt1.o%s;      static-pie:rcrt1.o%s;      !no-pie:Scrt1.o%s;      :crt1.o%s}    crti.o%s    %{static:crtbeginT.o%s;      shared|static-pie|!no-pie:crtbeginS.o%s;      :crtbegin.o%s}    %{fvtable-verify=none:%s;      fvtable-verify=preinit:vtv_start_preinit.o%s;      fvtable-verify=std:vtv_start.o%s}    %{fopenacc|fopenmp:crtoffloadbegin%O%s};:%{shared: crtbegin_so%O%s;:  %{static: crtbegin_static%O%s;: crtbegin_dynamic%O%s}}}

*cross_compile:
0

*version:
8.3.0

*multilib:
. !m32 !m64 !mx32;32:../lib32:i386-linux-gnu m32 !m64 !mx32;64:../lib:x86_64-linux-gnu !m32 m64 !mx32;x32:../libx32:x86_64-linux-gnux32 !m32 !m64 mx32;

*multilib_defaults:
m64

*multilib_extra:


*multilib_matches:
m32 m32;m64 m64;mx32 mx32;

*multilib_exclusions:


*multilib_options:
m32/m64/mx32

*multilib_reuse:


*linker:
collect2

*linker_plugin_file:


*lto_wrapper:


*lto_gcc:


*post_link:


*link_libgcc:
%D

*md_exec_prefix:


*md_startfile_prefix:


*md_startfile_prefix_1:


*startfile_prefix_spec:


*sysroot_spec:
--sysroot=%R

*sysroot_suffix_spec:


*sysroot_hdrs_suffix_spec:


*self_spec:


*cc1_cpu:
%{march=native:%>march=native %:local_cpu_detect(arch)   %{!mtune=*:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}} %{mtune=native:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}

*link_command:
%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:    %(linker) %{!fno-use-linker-plugin:%{!fno-lto:     -plugin %(linker_plugin_file)     -plugin-opt=%(lto_wrapper)     -plugin-opt=-fresolution=%u.res     %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%:pass-through-libs(%(link_gcc_c_sequence))}}     }}%{flto|flto=*:%<fcompare-debug*}     %{flto} %{fno-lto} %{flto=*} %l %{static|shared|r:;!no-pie:-pie} %{fuse-ld=*:-fuse-ld=%*}  %{gz|gz=zlib:--compress-debug-sections=zlib} %{gz=none:--compress-debug-sections=none} %{gz=zlib-gnu:--compress-debug-sections=zlib-gnu} %X %{o*} %{e*} %{N} %{n} %{r}    %{s} %{t} %{u*} %{z} %{Z} %{!nostdlib:%{!nostartfiles:%S}}     %{static|no-pie|static-pie:} %{L*} %(mfwrap) %(link_libgcc) %{fvtable-verify=none:} %{fvtable-verify=std:   %e-fvtable-verify=std is not supported in this configuration} %{fvtable-verify=preinit:   %e-fvtable-verify=preinit is not supported in this configuration} %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{%:sanitize(address):%{!shared:libasan_preinit%O%s} %{static-libasan:%{!shared:-Bstatic --whole-archive -lasan --no-whole-archive -Bdynamic}}%{!static-libasan:-lasan}}     %{%:sanitize(thread):%{!shared:libtsan_preinit%O%s} %{static-libtsan:%{!shared:-Bstatic --whole-archive -ltsan --no-whole-archive -Bdynamic}}%{!static-libtsan:-ltsan}}     %{%:sanitize(leak):%{!shared:liblsan_preinit%O%s} %{static-liblsan:%{!shared:-Bstatic --whole-archive -llsan --no-whole-archive -Bdynamic}}%{!static-liblsan:-llsan}}}} %o %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{mmpx:%{fcheck-pointer-bounds:    %{static:--whole-archive -lmpx --no-whole-archive %:include(libmpx.spec)%(link_libmpx)}    %{!static:%{static-libmpx:-Bstatic --whole-archive}    %{!static-libmpx:--push-state --no-as-needed} -lmpx     %{!static-libmpx:--pop-state}     %{static-libmpx:--no-whole-archive -Bdynamic %:include(libmpx.spec)%(link_libmpx)}}}}%{mmpx:%{fcheck-pointer-bounds:%{!fno-chkp-use-wrappers:    %{static:-lmpxwrappers}    %{!static:%{static-libmpxwrappers:-Bstatic}    -lmpxwrappers %{static-libmpxwrappers: -Bdynamic}}}}}}} %{mmpx:%{fcheck-pointer-bounds:%{!static:%{m16|m32|mx32:;:-z bndplt }}}}     %{fopenacc|fopenmp|%:gt(%{ftree-parallelize-loops=*:%*} 1):        %:include(libgomp.spec)%(link_gomp)}    %{fgnu-tm:%:include(libitm.spec)%(link_itm)}    %(mflib)  %{fsplit-stack: --wrap=pthread_create}    %{fprofile-arcs|fprofile-generate*|coverage:-lgcov} %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{%:sanitize(address): %{static-libasan|static:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libasan)}    %{static:%ecannot specify -static with -fsanitize=address}}    %{%:sanitize(thread): %{static-libtsan|static:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libtsan)}    %{static:%ecannot specify -static with -fsanitize=thread}}    %{%:sanitize(undefined):%{static-libubsan:-Bstatic} -lubsan %{static-libubsan:-Bdynamic} %{static-libubsan|static:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libubsan)}}    %{%:sanitize(leak): %{static-liblsan|static:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_liblsan)}}}}     %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%(link_ssp) %(link_gcc_c_sequence)}}    %{!nostdlib:%{!nostartfiles:%E}} %{T*}  
%(post_link) }}}}}}
```

10.2.1:

```js
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc -dumpspecs
*asm:
%{m16|m32:--32}  %{m16|m32|mx32:;:--64}  %{mx32:--x32}  %{msse2avx:%{!mavx:-msse2avx}}

*asm_debug:
%{%:debug-level-gt(0):%{gstabs*:--gstabs}%{!gstabs*:%{g*:--gdwarf2}}} %{fdebug-prefix-map=*:--debug-prefix-map %*}

*asm_final:
%{gsplit-dwarf: 
   objcopy --extract-dwo     %{c:%{o*:%*}%{!o*:%b%O}}%{!c:%U%O}      %{c:%{o*:%:replace-extension(%{o*:%*} .dwo)}%{!o*:%b.dwo}}%{!c:%b.dwo} 
   objcopy --strip-dwo       %{c:%{o*:%*}%{!o*:%b%O}}%{!c:%U%O}     }

*asm_options:
%{-target-help:%:print-asm-header()} %{v} %{w:-W} %{I*}  %{gz|gz=zlib:--compress-debug-sections=zlib} %{gz=none:--compress-debug-sections=none} %{gz=zlib-gnu:--compress-debug-sections=zlib-gnu} %a %Y %{c:%W{o*}%{!o*:-o %w%b%O}}%{!c:-o %d%w%u%O}

*invoke_as:
%{!fwpa*:   %{fcompare-debug=*|fdump-final-insns=*:%:compare-debug-dump-opt()}   %{!S:-o %|.s |
 as %(asm_options) %m.s %A }  }

*cpp:
%{posix:-D_POSIX_SOURCE} %{pthread:-D_REENTRANT}

*cpp_options:
%(cpp_unique_options) %1 %{m*} %{std*&ansi&trigraphs} %{W*&pedantic*} %{w} %{f*} %{g*:%{%:debug-level-gt(0):%{g*} %{!fno-working-directory:-fworking-directory}}} %{O*} %{undef} %{save-temps*:-fpch-preprocess} %(distro_defaults)

*cpp_debug_options:
%{d*}

*cpp_unique_options:
%{!Q:-quiet} %{nostdinc*} %{C} %{CC} %{v} %@{I*&F*} %{P} %I %{MD:-MD %{!o:%b.d}%{o*:%.d%*}} %{MMD:-MMD %{!o:%b.d}%{o*:%.d%*}} %{M} %{MM} %{MF*} %{MG} %{MP} %{MQ*} %{MT*} %{!E:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!MT:%{!MQ:%{MD|MMD:%{o*:-MQ %*}}}}}}} %{remap} %{g3|ggdb3|gstabs3|gxcoff3|gvms3:-dD} %{!iplugindir*:%{fplugin*:%:find-plugindir()}} %{H} %C %{D*&U*&A*} %{i*} %Z %i %{E|M|MM:%W{o*}}

*trad_capable_cpp:
cc1 -E %{traditional|traditional-cpp:-traditional-cpp}

*cc1:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-cc:%(cc1_cpu) %{profile:-p};:%(cc1_cpu) %{profile:-p} %{!mglibc:%{!muclibc:%{!mbionic: -mbionic}}} %{!fno-pic:%{!fno-PIC:%{!fpic:%{!fPIC: -fPIC}}}}}

*cc1_options:
%{pg:%{fomit-frame-pointer:%e-pg and -fomit-frame-pointer are incompatible}} %{!iplugindir*:%{fplugin*:%:find-plugindir()}} %1 %{!Q:-quiet} %{!dumpbase:-dumpbase %B} %{d*} %{m*} %{aux-info*} %{fcompare-debug-second:%:compare-debug-auxbase-opt(%b)}  %{!fcompare-debug-second:%{c|S:%{o*:-auxbase-strip %*}%{!o*:-auxbase %b}}}%{!c:%{!S:-auxbase %b}}  %{g*} %{O*} %{W*&pedantic*} %{w} %{std*&ansi&trigraphs} %{v:-version} %{pg:-p} %{p} %{f*} %{undef} %{Qn:-fno-ident} %{Qy:} %{-help:--help} %{-target-help:--target-help} %{-version:--version} %{-help=*:--help=%*} %{!fsyntax-only:%{S:%W{o*}%{!o*:-o %b.s}}} %{fsyntax-only:-o %j} %{-param*} %{coverage:-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage} %{fprofile-arcs|fprofile-generate*|coverage:   %{!fprofile-update=single:     %{pthread:-fprofile-update=prefer-atomic}}}

*cc1plus:


*link_gcc_c_sequence:
%{static|static-pie:--start-group} %G %{!nolibc:%L}    %{static|static-pie:--end-group}%{!static:%{!static-pie:%G}}

*distro_defaults:
%{!fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables:-fasynchronous-unwind-tables}

*link_ssp:
%{fstack-protector|fstack-protector-all|fstack-protector-strong|fstack-protector-explicit:}

*endfile:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{Ofast|ffast-math|funsafe-math-optimizations:crtfastmath.o%s}    %{mpc32:crtprec32.o%s}    %{mpc64:crtprec64.o%s}    %{mpc80:crtprec80.o%s} %{!static:%{fvtable-verify=none:%s;      fvtable-verify=preinit:vtv_end_preinit.o%s;      fvtable-verify=std:vtv_end.o%s}}    %{static:crtend.o%s;      shared|static-pie|!no-pie:crtendS.o%s;      :crtend.o%s} crtn.o%s %{fopenacc|fopenmp:crtoffloadend%O%s};:%{Ofast|ffast-math|funsafe-math-optimizations:crtfastmath.o%s}    %{mpc32:crtprec32.o%s}    %{mpc64:crtprec64.o%s}    %{mpc80:crtprec80.o%s} %{shared: crtend_so%O%s;: crtend_android%O%s}}

*link:
%{!r:--build-id} %{!static|static-pie:--eh-frame-hdr} %{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{m16|m32|mx32:;:-m elf_x86_64}                    %{m16|m32:-m elf_i386}                    %{mx32:-m elf32_x86_64}   --hash-style=gnu   --as-needed   %{shared:-shared}   %{!shared:     %{!static:       %{!static-pie:       %{rdynamic:-export-dynamic}     %{m16|m32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-i386.so.1;:/lib/ld-linux.so.2}}}}     %{m16|m32|mx32:;:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld64-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker64;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1;:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2}}}}     %{mx32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ldx32-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linkerx32;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-x32.so.1;:/libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2}}}}}}     %{static:-static} %{static-pie:-static -pie --no-dynamic-linker -z text}};:%{m16|m32|mx32:;:-m elf_x86_64}                    %{m16|m32:-m elf_i386}                    %{mx32:-m elf32_x86_64}   --hash-style=gnu   --as-needed   %{shared:-shared}   %{!shared:     %{!static:       %{!static-pie:  %{rdynamic:-export-dynamic}     %{m16|m32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-i386.so.1;:/lib/ld-linux.so.2}}}}     %{m16|m32|mx32:;:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld64-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker64;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1;:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2}}}}       %{mx32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ldx32-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linkerx32;:%{mmusl:/lib/ld-musl-x32.so.1;:/libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2}}}}}}     %{static:-static} %{static-pie:-static -pie --no-dynamic-linker -z text}} %{shared: -Bsymbolic}}

*lib:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{pthread:-lpthread} %{shared:-lc}    %{!shared:%{profile:-lc_p}%{!profile:-lc}};:%{shared:-lc}    %{!shared:%{profile:-lc_p}%{!profile:-lc}} %{!static: -ldl}}

*link_gomp:


*libgcc:
%{static|static-libgcc|static-pie:-lgcc -lgcc_eh}%{!static:%{!static-libgcc:%{!static-pie:%{!shared-libgcc:-lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state}%{shared-libgcc:-lgcc_s%{!shared: -lgcc}}}}}

*startfile:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{shared:;      pg|p|profile:%{static-pie:grcrt1.o%s;:gcrt1.o%s};      static:crt1.o%s;      static-pie:rcrt1.o%s;      !no-pie:Scrt1.o%s;      :crt1.o%s} crti.o%s    %{static:crtbeginT.o%s;      shared|static-pie|!no-pie:crtbeginS.o%s;      :crtbegin.o%s}    %{fvtable-verify=none:%s;      fvtable-verify=preinit:vtv_start_preinit.o%s;      fvtable-verify=std:vtv_start.o%s} %{fopenacc|fopenmp:crtoffloadbegin%O%s};:%{shared: crtbegin_so%O%s;:  %{static: crtbegin_static%O%s;: crtbegin_dynamic%O%s}}}

*cross_compile:
0

*version:
10.2.1

*multilib:
. !m32 !m64 !mx32;32:../lib32:i386-linux-gnu m32 !m64 !mx32;64:../lib:x86_64-linux-gnu !m32 m64 !mx32;x32:../libx32:x86_64-linux-gnux32 !m32 !m64 mx32;

*multilib_defaults:
m64

*multilib_extra:


*multilib_matches:
m32 m32;m64 m64;mx32 mx32;

*multilib_exclusions:


*multilib_options:
m32/m64/mx32

*multilib_reuse:


*linker:
collect2

*linker_plugin_file:


*lto_wrapper:


*lto_gcc:


*post_link:


*link_libgcc:
%D

*md_exec_prefix:


*md_startfile_prefix:


*md_startfile_prefix_1:


*startfile_prefix_spec:


*sysroot_spec:
--sysroot=%R

*sysroot_suffix_spec:


*sysroot_hdrs_suffix_spec:


*self_spec:


*cc1_cpu:
%{march=native:%>march=native %:local_cpu_detect(arch)   %{!mtune=*:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}} %{mtune=native:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}

*link_command:
%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:    %(linker) %{!fno-use-linker-plugin:%{!fno-lto:     -plugin %(linker_plugin_file)     -plugin-opt=%(lto_wrapper)     -plugin-opt=-fresolution=%u.res     %{flinker-output=*:-plugin-opt=-linker-output-known}     %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%:pass-through-libs(%(link_gcc_c_sequence))}}     }}%{flto|flto=*:%<fcompare-debug*}     %{flto} %{fno-lto} %{flto=*} %l %{static|shared|r:;!no-pie:-pie} %{fuse-ld=*:-fuse-ld=%*}  %{gz|gz=zlib:--compress-debug-sections=zlib} %{gz=none:--compress-debug-sections=none} %{gz=zlib-gnu:--compress-debug-sections=zlib-gnu} %X %{o*} %{e*} %{N} %{n} %{r}    %{s} %{t} %{u*} %{z} %{Z} %{!nostdlib:%{!r:%{!nostartfiles:%S}}}     %{static|no-pie|static-pie:} %@{L*} %(mfwrap) %(link_libgcc) %{fvtable-verify=none:} %{fvtable-verify=std:   %e-fvtable-verify=std is not supported in this configuration} %{fvtable-verify=preinit:   %e-fvtable-verify=preinit is not supported in this configuration} %{!nostdlib:%{!r:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{%:sanitize(address):%{!shared:libasan_preinit%O%s} %{static-libasan:%{!shared:-Bstatic --whole-archive -lasan --no-whole-archive -Bdynamic}}%{!static-libasan:%{!fuse-ld=gold:--push-state} --no-as-needed -lasan %{fuse-ld=gold:--as-needed;:--pop-state}}}     %{%:sanitize(thread):%{!shared:libtsan_preinit%O%s} %{static-libtsan:%{!shared:-Bstatic --whole-archive -ltsan --no-whole-archive -Bdynamic}}%{!static-libtsan:%{!fuse-ld=gold:--push-state} --no-as-needed -ltsan %{fuse-ld=gold:--as-needed;:--pop-state}}}     %{%:sanitize(leak):%{!shared:liblsan_preinit%O%s} %{static-liblsan:%{!shared:-Bstatic --whole-archive -llsan --no-whole-archive -Bdynamic}}%{!static-liblsan:%{!fuse-ld=gold:--push-state} --no-as-needed -llsan %{fuse-ld=gold:--as-needed;:--pop-state}}}}}} %o      %{fopenacc|fopenmp|%:gt(%{ftree-parallelize-loops=*:%*} 1):     %:include(libgomp.spec)%(link_gomp)}    %{fgnu-tm:%:include(libitm.spec)%(link_itm)}    %(mflib)  %{fsplit-stack: --wrap=pthread_create}    %{fprofile-arcs|fprofile-generate*|coverage:-lgcov} %{!nostdlib:%{!r:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{%:sanitize(address): %{static-libasan|static:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libasan)}    %{static:%ecannot specify -static with -fsanitize=address}}    %{%:sanitize(thread): %{static-libtsan|static:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libtsan)}    %{static:%ecannot specify -static with -fsanitize=thread}}    %{%:sanitize(undefined):%{static-libubsan:-Bstatic} %{!static-libubsan:--push-state --no-as-needed} -lubsan  %{static-libubsan:-Bdynamic} %{!static-libubsan:--pop-state} %{static-libubsan|static:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libubsan)}}    %{%:sanitize(leak): %{static-liblsan|static:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_liblsan)}}}}}     %{!nostdlib:%{!r:%{!nodefaultlibs:%(link_ssp) %(link_gcc_c_sequence)}}}    %{!nostdlib:%{!r:%{!nostartfiles:%E}}} %{T*}  
%(post_link) }}}}}}
```

Comment: Both "int var" and "int var = 5" are definitions, and both are declarations.

Comment: "Pretty much as canonical as it gets" Uh... no. There is very broad consensus stating that defining variables in header files is very bad practice, and also that using global variables is very bad practice.

Comment: See [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1433204/15168)

Comment: See the release notes for [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html) — the last bullet-point under the section on C.  That documents the change in default behaviour from `-fcommon` (before 10.1.0) to `-fno-common` (10.1.0 onwards).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes there was a change in behaviour.

In C you are supposed to only define a global variable in one translation unit, other translation unit that want to access the variable should declare it as "extern".

In your code, a.h is included in both a.c and main.c so the variable is defined twice. To fix this you should change the "int test" in a.h to "extern int test", then add "int test" to a.c to define the variable exactly once.

---

In C a definition of a global variable that does not initialise the variable is considered "tentative". You can have multiple tentative definitions of a variable in the same compilation unit. Multiple tentative defintions in different compilation units are not allowed in standard C, but were historically allowed by C compilers on unix systems.

Older versions of gcc would allow multiple tenative definitions (but not multiple non-tentative definitions) of a global variable in different compilation units by default. gcc-10 does not. You can restore the old behavior with the command line option "-fcommon" but this is discouraged.

Comment: Older versions of GCC would not “tolerate multiple definitions of a global variable by default.” E.g., given `int x = 3; int x = 4;` outside of any function, compiling and linking would result in an error. Older versions of GCC would mark a definition arising solely from a *tentative definition* as “common,” and the linker would, and still does, coalesce common definitions of a symbol into a single definition. Ordinary definitions would not be marked as common and would cause multiple-definition errors.

Comment: Additional information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67270401/298225), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66056029/298225), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64844348/298225).

Comment: Re “In C a definition of a global variable that does not initialise the variable is considered "tentative".”: In spite of the name, a *tentative definition* is not a definition, and so it is not a definition that is considered tentative. It is in fact a declaration, and that is why you may have multiple instances of the same one in a translation unit; `int x; int x; int x;` is fine. Where a definition arises is that, if there are one or more tentative definitions and no (real) definition by the end of the translation unit, then a definition will come into effect.

Comment: Re “Multiple tentative defintions in different compilation units are not allowed in standard C”: Multiple tentative definitions are allowed. The behavior is not defined by the C standard. It was not defined because there were different practices by different C implementations, and the C committee chose not to codify them, so the reason it is undefined is in fact to allow different uses of it.

Comment: thank you for a beautiful step by step guide to fixing the problem!

Answer (score 7):

You can try to set -fcommon compile option to ignore multi-define in c code since gcc-10.
Ref:https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html

Comment: That's a cop-out — it should only be a short-term measure.  The standard does not support the 'common' extension, though it does mention that it exists in [§J.5.11 Multiple external definitions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.11): _There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined._  (It cross-references [§6.9.2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2) which says that is not allowed.)