# How to run the first version of git from 2005?

Tags: c, git, macos, gcc, linker

The first version of git appeared in 2005. For curiosity and learning purposes, I'm trying to get it to run. Source code **[here](https://github.com/git/git/tree/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290)**. There are very few files, so it seems reasonable, however I'm getting stuck due to lack of knowledge of C-specifics.

**What step-by-step instructions will get [this](https://github.com/git/git/tree/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290) to run on macOS (preferably) or FreeBSD, modifying the files as needed?**

### Attempt 1

Using **macOS Big Sur**:

1. in `Makefile`, change `install $(PROG) $(HOME)/bin/` to `install $(PROG) ./bin/`
   This is to let binaries resides in the local directory.
2. in `cache.h`, add the lines `#include <string.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`.
3. `brew install openssl`
4. `ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl .`
5. `make install`

**Result**: Wall of errors and warnings including `"no member named 'st_ctim' in 'struct stat'"`, `"no member named 'st_mtim' in 'struct stat'"`, etc.

### Attempt 2

Using **FreeBSD 12**:

1. in `Makefile`, change `install $(PROG) $(HOME)/bin/` to `install $(PROG) ./bin/`
   This is to let binaries resides in the local directory.
2. in `cache.h`, add the lines `#include <string.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`.
3. `make install`

Linker errors:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: read-cache.o:cache.h:64: multiple definition of `sha1_file_directory'; update-cache.o:cache.h:64: first defined here
/usr/local/bin/ld: read-cache.o:cache.h:65: multiple definition of `active_cache'; update-cache.o:cache.h:65: first defined here
/usr/local/bin/ld: read-cache.o:cache.h:66: multiple definition of `active_nr'; update-cache.o:cache.h:66: first defined here
/usr/local/bin/ld: read-cache.o:cache.h:66: multiple definition of `active_alloc'; update-cache.o:cache.h:66: first defined here
/usr/local/bin/ld: update-cache.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SHA1_Init@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
/usr/local/bin/ld: /lib/libcrypto.so.111: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
```

---

I'm hitting a wall, because I notice my knowledge of C and gcc is too limited to proceed. What are some pointers to make this work for macOS (preferably) or FreeBSD (otherwise)?

Comment: @Michael The question is too broad for this site, basically (I didn't DV or close).

Comment: @PaulSanders I appreciate the clarification, now I better understand the need expressed by the downvote and how to improve my communication. Moreover, thanks to your pointer, I could find a post on "too broad" over at meta that helped me understand better: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259857/409246 — As a side-note, I wonder, since StackOverflow may not be the right place to get unstuck on this issue, if there are other places on the internet to turn to instead?

Comment: Pick out the individual problems, one at a time. Each one may well be suited to SO: for instance, "this 2005 C code expects unistd.h to do X, now it does Y, how do X and Y relate and what incompatibilities can I expect". You'll probably find that each of these is *already answered*, too!

Comment: @torek I appreciate your comment. I think I follow the strategy—if the problem seems beyond a certain size, then do this: instead of asking the big question, break it down into subproblems and ask the subproblem on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original version of Git was almost certainly only targeted toward Linux and not toward any other systems.  Consequently, portability issues were probably not resolved.

*This is, at most, a partial solution to your problems — it should help you with one aspect of the troubles you identify.*

You say:

> Result: Wall of errors and warnings including "`no member named 'st_ctim' in 'struct stat'`", "`no member named 'st_mtim' in 'struct stat'`", etc.

That feature requires a macOS-specific macro to be defined:

```
/* To get the 64-bit inode structure with struct timespec elements on Mac OS X */
#define _DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE
```

The names of the structure elements are not consistent with POSIX.  In my code, I use:

```
#define ST_ATIME st_atimespec
#define ST_BTIME st_birthtimespec
#define ST_CTIME st_ctimespec
#define ST_MTIME st_mtimespec
```

The POSIX variants use (file birth time is not part of POSIX):

```
#define ST_ATIME st_atim
#define ST_CTIME st_ctim
#define ST_MTIME st_mtim
```

For systems other than macOS and POSIX-compliant systems, I use these (and the type of the members is `time_t`, not `struct timespec`):

```
#define ST_ATIME st_atime
#define ST_CTIME st_ctime
#define ST_MTIME st_mtime
```

That's one part of the issue — you also have to find where `st_ctim` etc are used and revise the code to handle the portability issues.  For example, one piece of code reads:

```
    struct stat *sb;

    …

        case 'a':
            pr_format_date(sb->ST_ATIME);
            break;
        case 'c':
            pr_format_date(sb->ST_CTIME);
            break;
        case 'm':
            pr_format_date(sb->ST_MTIME);
            break;
```

The called function is passed a `Time *`, where the code has one of these in effect:

```
typedef struct timespec Time;
typedef time_t          Time;
```

The body of the function has different code for when `Time` is a `struct timespec` and when it is a `time_t`.

Comment: I very much appreciate how you answered this question, Jonathan. I felt way out of my depth and didn't know how to proceed. Your pointers gave me the information needed to continue. Thank you. :)

Comment: Life might be easier working under Linux in a VM.  VirtualBox works and is free (I use it a lot).

Answer (score 0):

For **FreeBSD 12**, I managed to get it to run as follows:

1. in `Makefile`, modify as follows:

   - change `install $(PROG) $(HOME)/bin/` to `install $(PROG) ./bin/`
     This is to let binaries reside in the local directory.
   - change `LIBS= -lssl` to `LIBS= -lssl -lcrypto -lz`
     This gives the linker access to the hashing and compression libraries.
2. in `cache.h`, modify as follows:

   - add the lines `#include <string.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`.
   - add `extern` in front of the lines 64-66.
     See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69908511) for background on this change in GCC's behavior.
3. `make install`

---

### As an aside: How to use this

- **`init-db`**
  Initialize a `.dircache` folder in the current directory. Per default, objects are put into `.dircache/objects`.

  *Note: This command is related to the modern `git init` and the `.git` folder.*
- **`update-cache`** <list of files that have been changed/added/deleted>
  *Note: this is related to modern `git add`.*
- **`show-diff`**
  Show changes; do files need to be added?
  *Note: this is similar to modern `git diff`*.
- **`cat-file`** <sha1>
  *Note: akin to modern `git cat-file`.*