# defining extern variable inside of the scope and outside of the scope

Tags: c, syntax

I defined extern a in the scope and outside of the scope

a.c

```
int a;

void foo(void)
{
    a = 3;
}
```

b.c

```
extern int a = 10; /*same as "extern a; int a = 10?" */


void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Is this code well-defined?

Comment: `int a;` defines the variable. Yet `extern int a = 10;` *also* defines it. There should be only one definition. So I suggest you change it to `int a = 10;` in the first file and `extern int a;` in the second file, which makes it only a declaration.

Comment: I think this shows a general lack of understanding of the extern keyword, not that there is anything wrong with that, how ever I dug through my notes and flagged this as a decent source that explains the keyword. https://www.journaldev.com/38985/extern-keyword-in-c

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: someone asked this to me.

Comment: @도라에몽1 It's better to declare the variable in a header file.

Comment: But in a.c "int a" isn't a  temptative definitions?

Comment: if a.c "int a=3" b.c "int a" a=3 is external linkage so doesn't int a terns out to external int a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extern int a = 10;` is the same as `int a = 10;`

If you have both the code will not link as there will be multiple definitions of the static storage variable `a` in your project.

Comment: It's UB with no diagnostic required, so there is not necessarily a link error

Answer (score 2):

This causes undefined behaviour in Standard C due to multiple definition of `a`.

There is a common extension for implementations to allow multiple definition so long as at most one is initialized.

For more detail see: [Is having global variables in common blocks an undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587124/)

---

`extern int a = 10;` is the same as `int a = 10;` which is the same as `extern int a; int a = 10;`  .  Variable definitions have external linkage unless specified as static (or the identifier already declared as static in the same scope).

Comment: thank you but int a; is temptative definition and there is external definition so doesn't int a changes to declaration? is it still definition?