# Why is extern required for global variable on Linux but not Mac when compiling shared object?

Tags: c, gcc, extern

I have written a small C library that I am trying to compile to a shared object.  When compiling on my Mac, where gcc links to clang, the code compiles just fine with or without the `extern` keyword.  When I compile on Linux, I get an error unless I include the `extern`.

Here is a MWE:

include/common.h

```
#ifndef _COMMON_H_
#define _COMMON_H_

extern int x; /* Omitting extern causes error on Linux */

#endif
```

include/sample.h

```
#ifndef _SAMPLE_H_
#define _SAMPLE_H_

#include "common.h"

#endif
```

src/common.c

```
#include "common.h"
```

src/sample.c

```
#include "sample.h"
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -c -Iinclude -fPIC src/*
gcc *.o -shared -o libsample.so
```

This is the error on Linux:

```
/usr/bin/ld: build/common.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `x'; build/category.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
```

I googled a bit, but I'm still not sure what is happening here.  Is the code without the `extern` incorrect, or is there some issue with the compiler?  Or is there some difference in what `-fPIC` does on Mac vs. Linux?  I've only dabbled in C, but I don't recall ever needing to declare global variables as extern before.

Comment: Without `extern`, each compilation unit including the header has a different `int x`.

Comment: It depends upon the compiler [and its version]. For many years, `gcc` [and other compilers] defaulted to `-fcommon`. But, `gcc` starting with version 12.x.x(?) defaults to `-fno-common` See my answer: [Global variables and the .data section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627070/5382650) The TL;DR: Just add `-fcommon` to the command line.

Comment: Yes, the code without `extern` is incorrect.  For largely historical reasons, however, some compilers will accept it. But note well that the code *with* `extern` is also incorrect, unless there is also a *bona fide* definition of `x` somewhere else.

Comment: I think I now have a better understanding of the extern keyword, and I can see that the compiler plays a big role in terms of how it is implemented.